# Rally Project's Revision History using JAVA API

Tags: java, api, rally, revision-history

I would like to get the Revision History for Project. I want to find the Project which contains the Revision Description as "**PARENT changed from**" and its **LastUpdateddate** .I tried the following code, it threw Null Pointer exception. Was my Query used in this code correct? Please help.

```
try {
        QueryRequest projectRequest = new QueryRequest("Project");
        projectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "Revisions", "LastUpdateDate"));
        projectRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        projectRequest.setProject(projectRef);
        projectRequest.setScopedDown(true);
        //projectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "PARENT changed from"));  
        projectRequest.setLimit(queryLimit);
        QueryResponse projectQueryResponse = restApi.query(projectRequest);
        int count = projectQueryResponse.getResults().size();
        System.out.println(count);
        if (count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                JsonObject projectObject = projectQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println("Project: " + projectObject.get("_refObjectName"));
                //                   int numberOfRevisions = projectObject.getAsJsonObject("RevisionHistory").get("Count").getAsInt();
                // if(numberOfRevisions > 0) {
                QueryRequest revRequest = new QueryRequest(projectObject.getAsJsonObject("Revisions"));
                System.out.println (restApi.query(revRequest).getResults());
                JsonObject revhistory = restApi.query(revRequest).getResults();
                                            for (int j=0;j<numberOfRevisions;j++){
                                                //System.out.println(revhistory.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("_refObjectName").getAsString());
                                            }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the RevisionHistory collection for Rally Projects is not available through Webservices API. It is available for Workspaces.

I have filed this as a Defect with Rally Engineering. You may wish to [file a case with Rally Support](http://www.rallydev.com/open-support-case) if you wish to receive updates on the issue, including a notification at such time as a fix may become available. There's no time estimate on a fix at this time.

Comment: Is there way to obtain this using JavaScript? or is there no way to Relate Project object with Revision History Object?

Comment: Unfortunately, because this collection is not available to WSAPI, it cannot be obtained via any REST call, whether java, javascript, ruby, etc. Sorry for the hassles.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your information. I will add the same as Idea. Thanks

Comment: I've actually filed this as a Defect with Rally Engineering and have edited the answer to reflect this. Sorry for the troubles.